# Dont see flag in header

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have two flags in header ( im using customizr theme ), but in Chrome I see only 1 flag and in firefox 2 flags.

In Google Chrome:

[image]

and in Mozille Firefox:

[image]

My Question is, why I see only 1 flag in chrome ?

My code for this :

```
<header class="<?php echo implode( " ", apply_filters('tc_header_classes', array('tc-header' ,'clearfix', 'row-fluid') ) ) ?>" role="banner">
        <div style = 'position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 20px;'>
                <a href = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/et/'><img src = 'http://www.wizards.com/events/images/flag_Estonia.jpg' /></a>
                <a href = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/en/'><img src = 'http://www.hans-pedersen.com/en/img/icon-english.gif' /></a>
        </div>

        <div style = 'position: absolute; right: 100px; top: 10px; z-index: 201'>
                <?php wp_loginout(); ?>
        </div>
            <div style = 'position: relative; right: 80px;'>
            <?php 
                // The '__header' hook is used with the following callback functions (ordered by priorities) : 
                //TC_header_main::$instance->tc_logo_title_display(), TC_header_main::$instance->tc_tagline_display(), TC_header_main::$instance->tc_navbar_display()
                do_action( '__header' );
            ?>
            </div>
        </header>
```

I already tried to move flags right position to 40,100, ... But nothing.

Can somebody help me or give some clue :)  Thanks !

Comment: Can you please give me the site link?? I will provide you solution I hope its css problem!

Comment: Sorry, but its in localhost :S

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the position styles from flags div because of this one flags not appear properly. Just empty for now and than check where flags displayed.

```
<div style = ''>
   <a href = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/et/'><img src = 'http://www.wizards.com/events/images/flag_Estonia.jpg' /></a>
   <a href = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/en/'><img src = 'http://www.hans-pedersen.com/en/img/icon-english.gif' /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: if both flags display some where on the header it mean your top and right positions are right. Just adjust again

Comment: I can see only one flag in Chrome, Its wierd, like a 1 week ago all works and now is one flag dissapeared.

Comment: I have seen in screen shot you have just logged In with any user. Can you please logged out and than check in chrome.?

Comment: In IE I see also only one flag

Comment: Its soo broken. If im loged in in Firefox then I see these flags in right position and If im logged out then I see these flags( Only in home page ) in left ( without this  `style = 'position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 20px;' `)

Comment: Actually this is unseen for me otherwise I can easily solve the cross browsing issue for you .. It look like that something hidden this flag like any other div or header html.